# Why is jhipster not updating

Tags: java, angularjs, jhipster

I want to install primeng 7.0.0 to my Angular project but first I need to update my JHipster to last version.

```
-jhipster upgrade --target-version=5.7.0
```

when I write this command to terminal I get the following error

> Error: ERROR! Exiting process
>       at Environment.error (C:\Users\yagmur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-environment\lib\environment.js:157:40)
>       at module.exports.error (C:\Users\yagmur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\generator-base.js:2444:18)
>       at gitExec (C:\Users\yagmur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\upgrade\index.js:235:30)
>       at C:\Users\yagmur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipst
>
> er\node_modules\shelljs\src\exec.js:118:9
>       at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:285:7)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5) Emitted 'error' event at:
>       at Environment.error (C:\Users\yagmur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-environment\lib\environment.js:159:15)
>       at module.exports.error (C:\Users\yagmur\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\generator-base.js:2444:18)
>       [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)

Comment: I would like to upgrade from 5.3.1 to 5.7.0

Comment: Could you please edit your question and paste full error? The meaningful part is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing it rather than upgrading it?

```
jhipster install @5.7.0
```